# Moving jquery sortable placeholder

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-sortable

I am using jquery sortable. I have a problem:
Because of some reasons my list wrapper (ul) is 'inline' and it doesn't wrap all 'li' elements (as you know). In some cases I push placeholder in list manually (appending to the end of list). But after that action when I am dragging over the list placeholder is at the same position.
How can I manually place placeholder everywhere I need? Do I probably need to trigger some events? Or something like that? for correct plugin work.

Thanks.

Comment: Does it help to re-initialize sortable after moving?

Comment: Problem is 'while moving', not after...

Comment: I see, I'll probably have to see the code or the whole page to help you more.